# Android: onCreateOptionsMenu - Remove Default Menu Item

Tags: android, oncreateoptionsmenu

I am using the `onCreateOptionsMenu` and there is a default menu item that I did not program. I would like to remove it because I have no use for it and it does not do anything. Here is what it looks like:

[image]

I would like to get rid of the "Settings" item.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add(1, 1, 0, "item1");
    menu.add(1, 2, 1, "item2");

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_name, menu);
    return true;
}
```

As you can see, I have not manually added it myself. How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As you can see, I have not added it myself

Yes, you have. It is coming from:

```
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_name, menu);
```

> How do I get rid of it?

Remove the aforementioned line. Or, move your Java-based `Menu` manipulations to `res/menu/activity_name.xml` and get rid of "Settings" from that file.

Comment: I thought the getMenuInflater is what causes the list to pop up. So by removing that, wouldn't that cause the menu to not open?

Comment: @lord_sneed: "I thought the getMenuInflater is what causes the list to pop up" -- no. "So by removing that, wouldn't that cause the menu to not open?" -- no. You can test this by getting rid of the line. Or, you can read the documentation for the `inflate()` method on `MenuInflater` to learn what it does: http://goo.gl/3WI23

Comment: This is the first time I have ever dealt with the onCreateOptionsMenu, so my apologies for not really paying attention to the menu folder in /res in the past. I only started teaching myself all of this no more than two months ago.

Answer (score 2):

The settings option is automatically generated in the menu xml by eclipse. Remove it from the xml menu and that option will be no longer shown.

Answer (score 0):

check the content of R.menu.activity_name or past the data of this xml file.